# format file size in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/2/)

If I upload more than 2MB file its not taking. My need is,

1) For example, If I upload 5MB file also, I need to convert is less than 50kb or less.

2) If file size is big, its taking more time to load, and its spoiling my performance.

So how can I convert the file size as less than in KB, if I upload more than 5 or 10MB also.

```js
$(function() {
  var fileInput = $('.upload-file');
  var maxSize = fileInput.data('max-size');
  $('.upload-form').submit(function(e) {
    if (fileInput.get(0).files.length) {
      var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
      if (fileSize > maxSize) {
        alert('file size is more then' + maxSize + ' bytes');
        return false;
      } else {
        alert('file size is correct- ' + fileSize + ' bytes');
      }
    } else {
      alert('choose file, please');
      return false;
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="upload-form">
  <input class="upload-file" data-max-size="2048" type="file">
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Any other easiest method is there in angularjs? Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say it but NO, there is no easy way to compress all files, otherwise it would be the norm. Lots of file formats already use compression to keep file sizes down e.g PNG, JPEG, MP3, MS Office documents and so on, more than can be listed here.

If the file is already compressed then no amount of compression is *likely* to make much improvement in the size.

Maximum upload size is usually controlled by the server that it is being uploaded to an the time taken to upload is governed by the network between client and host. If the user is trying to upload a 10Mb file over a good 3G connection at around 6Mbps then it's going to take around 8 seconds. No way round physics I'm afraid.

The only thing you could possibly do would be to manage the user's expectations, show a loading spinner and make them wait. Modern browsers will allow you to upload files using XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) allowing the page to continue doing other things while the upload is taking place.